# Convert curve to particle hair guide

Tags: particles, bezier-curves

I have created curves for a character's eyelash,I wonder if it is possible to convert them to particle hair guides so that I can use children and other control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two free add-ons for Blender that can convert curves and sheets (hair cards) to hair particles guides:

- HairNet 0.6.3 (https://github.com/Jandals/HairNet/releases)
   [forum thread at blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/hair-guides-created-from-mesh-objects/572642/191)
- Particle Hair Guides (https://github.com/Lichtso/hair_guides)
   [forum thread at blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/particle-hair-from-meshes-bezier-curves-nurbs/1154670)

The add-on *[Select Islands by Face Count](https://blenderartists.org/t/select-all-meshes-with-same-number-of-faces-in-edit-mode/1194005/3)* by *Stan_Pancakes* is a useful helper if you want to convert hair cards to particles with one of the add-ons above.