# Transfer particle system

Tags: particles

I am currently trying to make my first grooming in blender. My sculpt has too many polygons which makes it impossible to work with weight paint and then eventually with particle systems. It’s is extremely laggy even though I can’t even hear my pc (AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 6-Core, GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, 16gb RAM)

My idea to fix: I used instant mesh to create a low poly of obj of my sculpt and then work on that one. The only problem is, I have no clue if I can then just copy the particle systems to my original sculpt.

Question: is this the correct way to do it? If yes: is it possible to just transfer the groomed hair, beard etc? If no: Is there a better fix?

Kindest regards
Habib

Comment: AFAIK an edited hair particle system cannot be copied But you can convert it to a mesh (turn off the children) and then use the HairNet addon to re-create the edit on another mesh. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/205226/107598, and here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/212876/107598

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I am not sure if this is what I am looking for: I would love to groom and basically finish the hair before I transfer it to my final sculpt.

Comment: Or maybe just fix something in my setup? The tutorials I am watching also have high poly meshes and the workflow looks fluid. Maybe there is a fix here? Since I would love to use the blender in built particle grooming system, I don't like the idea of fitting hair particles on a hair like mesh

Comment: You can have a high-poly sculpted mesh with particle hair. A common workflow is to make a low-poly haircap. That's a mesh that is duplicated and separated from the head where the hair is placed. Use the remesh or decimate modifier to reduce the number of vertices.  Then add the particle system (=emitter), and groom/edit the hair as you like.

Comment: The linked workaround is not about *"the idea of fitting hair particles on a hair-like mesh"*. You can do this but in this case, it's used to duplicate an edited hair particles system from one mesh to another. This is not possible in Blender and you need the HairNet addon for this job. The described workaround is: edited particle hair => converted to mesh => hair particles created by HairNet addon from this mesh. The re-created hair will be the same as the original but it's added to another character's head/haircap. Of course, you need to choose the same Particle System settings in HairNet.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answers but I think I found my mistake. I have to retopologize my model. I just have way to many polygons on it - when I click tab, the sculpt is basically black. On the hair tutorial model, you can clearly see all polygons. Do you think this might solve it before I start working into retopology?

Comment: Yes, retopology should solve the issue. If you want to texture or animate the sculpt, you will definitely need to create a retopology.

Comment: Hey man, so it’s been 4 days now and am still working on the topology I was wondering if I could maybe improve my weight paint performance with higher ram (from 16gb to let’s say 64gb)? Since I don’t necessarily need the sculpt for modeling or gaming, but just for weight paint and particle system, I’m trying to find a way to skip this torturous manual labor