# Copy hair from one head to another?

Tags: sculpting, hair

I created a hair on a head with sculpt mode.
I'd like to have similar hair on another head.
Is there a way for me to copy it, or do I have to redo it again?

Regards

Comment: Have you used the (old) Hair Particle System or the (new) Hair Curves? To transfer the hair made by the Particle System you need an add-on like HairNet (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205226/convert-curve-to-particle-hair-guide). Convert the particles to mesh (=edges), then use the add-on to create a new particle system from the mesh (example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/212876/107598).