# Hairnet addon issues

Tags: particles, add-on, error, hair

I've been trying to use the hairnet addon in 3.0, the opinions "sheet" and "curve" work just fine, but using fibermesh, gives me this error no matter what [image]

Then I tried using hairnet in 2.9, thinking it was because of 3.0, I used hairnet 6.2. Then I get this new error from fibermesh [image]

The mesh [image]

and the seams [image]

I've tried multiple objects that would have the hair grow on them, nothing changed.

Are there other addons/resources that turns meshes into hair particles? Or is there a way to fix these errors?

Comment: How does your fiber mesh look like? I've just tried HairNet 0.6.6 with Blender 3.0 and it worked.

Comment: @Blunder let me give the image of the mesh, but fibermesh is doing this with any object, not just the one I'm trying to use it on

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh is not a fiber. Fiber is a mesh that has only (vertical) edges that represent the hair strands. Each edge must have the same number of vertices.

Fiber example:

[image: fiber example]

You could use the *Tris to Quads* operation, and remove all faces and edges except the "vertical" edges. An *Array* modifier could add some depth.

Comment: Thank you for telling me, but I want to know, are there any methods or addons capable of displaying meshes like mine as hair? If not I'll use what you told me

Comment: The only other add-on I know is *Particle Hair Guides* by *Lichtso* (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212638/107598). It's inspired by HairNet but it looks like it can handle grid meshes (edges with vertical edges). The mesh must be a quad mesh, too. Both add-ons work very well to convert hair cards and particle hair that got converted to mesh back to particle hair. For a "hair block" they don't work.

Comment: Does it work well in 3.0?

Comment: Checked, it doesn't